# securing APIs: JWT as OAuth2 bearer token vs. JWT directly

Tags: oauth, jwt

Google APIs have a [mechanism for server-to-server authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  I believe this is the OAuth2 JWT bearer flow.

In this model, the API consumer uses a JWT to get an access token, and then uses the access token to make API calls.

I've also read about [using JWT as OAuth2 access tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710783/may-an-oauth-2-0-access-token-be-a-jwt).

What I'd like to understand is, why couldn't you just use a JWT to access Google APIs directly?  What extra value does the access token provide?

Apologize if this is a naive question.

Comment: hope this helps...https://auth0.com/blog/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/#token-oauth