# JWT access tokens: a contradiction?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, microservices, openid-connect

I'm attempting to implement a security solution for a micro-services architecture.  My authentication server supports OAuth2 and OIDC.

I'm trying to figure out if I can pass a JWT token between my micro-services to avoid having to repeatedly exchange an opaque token to get the user's claims.  There's nothing (practical) that stops me doing that.  I can:

- Use the JWT (ID token) I get from the auth server as a bearer token when making the calls.
- Each service can validate that token against the auth server's (cached) JWKS to make sure it's valid
- Each service can include the token on it's calls to other services

I've read that [it's ok for an access token to be a JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710783/may-an-oauth-2-0-access-token-be-a-jwt?rq=1).

Great, but:

[image: should I?]

My (moral?) issue is this:

A **JWT** is intended for a [specific audience](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.3).  In fact the spec basically says that if it's not for you, you should reject it.

A **Bearer token** is [intended to be non-audience specific](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-1.2).  So if I issue a token that says that the bearer can read my mail, it can get passed through half a dozen different services, any one of which should be able to read my mail.

So my question is simply, how can a JWT be a bearer token?

*Bonus points for links to any nice articles/videos/examples of an effective distributed authentication solution!*

Comment: You can take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40375508/whats-the-difference-between-jwts-and-bearer-token *JWT can be used for many things, among those are bearer tokens, i.e. a piece of information that you can present to some service that by virtue of you having it (you being the "bearer") grants you access to something.*

Comment: Hence the contradiction!  I call service X with a token.  Service X calls service Y with the token.  If it's an opaque token, fine.  If it's a JWT then one of those services just broke the rules (since they can't both be the intended audience).

Comment: I asked a similar question some time back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710783/may-an-oauth-2-0-access-token-be-a-jwt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A JWT is intended for a specific audience. In fact the spec basically says that if it's not for you, you should reject it.

This is the case also for a bearer token.  It can be passed on by anyone, but only the audience should act on its validity.

So, service X can get a JWT bearer token with intended audience service Y.  It will not give the calling client any authorization based on that, but calling service Y with it does not violate the audience claim.  What would violate the audience claim is if service X validates the JWT, seeing the mismatching audience and says "Well, since the client has a JWT stating that it is user Fubar, I can return some info about user Fubar.".

The difference for an opaque non-JWT bearer token is that service X would have no way to misuse it...

Comment: Ahhh.  Of course.  I misread the spec.  It doesn't matter who a token comes _from_ but it is important who it _goes to_.  Thanks!